# JQuery, how to show class within class if class exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, navigation

For my Wordpress theme, I am trying to access and show the sub-menu within the list item that has the class .current-page-item

Currently I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $(".current-page-item").find(".sub-menu").show();
});
```

If I put an Alert('whatup'); inside the if statement, it will display the alert however it will not show(); the UL with the class .sub-menu

Could anyone help me out please?

Edit:
Here is the HTML code wordpress generates:

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-11">
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/subfolder/wordpress/">ABOUT COMPANY</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost:8080/subfolder/wordpress/?page_id=15">TEAM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10">
        <a href="http://localhost:8080/subfolder/wordpress/?page_id=7">COMPANY PHILOSOPHY</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://localhost:8080/subfolder/wordpress/?page_id=19">STRATEGY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That `if` condition is totally not needed.

Comment: Can you provide your markup and ideally a working example on jsfiddle.net? I don't think there is enough information currently.

Comment: You need to show the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: If the parent is hidden, showing the child element will do nothing.

Comment: Added HTML as well, and I know it is not needed I was testing to see if it actually worked in the first place.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/C7yFE/

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't seem to work for me.. I added the code wordpress generates into the post, see anything that would cause it to stop working?

Comment: The class is `current_page_item`, not `current-page-item`.

Comment: The reason why the if condition was true is because jQuery returns an empty jQuery object if the selectors don't match anything, and an object is always truthy. You should use `$(".current-page-item").find(".sub-menu").length > 0` to test if an element exists.

Comment: Ahh thank you I should have seen that! It's working now. Ok thanks I've changed that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your HTML structure, just do like this:

```
$("#menu-main").find("li.current_page_item").find("ul.sub-menu").show();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u44Yn/1/

Note that your code not working because the class of your `li` is `current_page_item` not `current-page-item`